# Combine two numpy array together

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have two numpy array like this,

this is the first one, called "pred_test"

```
array([2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 3., 2., 2., 3., 2., 2., 2., 2.,
       2., 3., 3.], dtype=float32)
```

and this is the second one, called "pred_train"

```
array([13., 11.,  9.,  5.,  5.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  4.,  5., 11.,
        9.,  9.,  4.,  4.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  1., 11., 12.,
        8.,  3.,  3.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  3.,  2.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  2.,  3.,  2.,
        2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2., 10.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
        2.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  2.,  3.,  3.],
      dtype=float32)
```

How can i combine the two array to look like pred_train + pred test, something like this..

```
    [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 3., 2., 2., 3., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3.,
     13., 11.,  9.,  5.,  5.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  4.,  5., 11.,
     9.,  9.,  4.,  4.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  1., 11., 12.,
     8.,  3.,  3.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  3.,  2.,
     1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  2.,  3.,  2.,
     2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2., 10.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
     2.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  2.,  3.,  3.]
```

Can someone help me? Thank you..

Comment: u can use [numpy.append](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.concatenate((pred_test, pred_train))`

Answer (score 0):

You can go with:

```
np.append(pred_test, pred_train)
```